# Find placeholder substring

Tags: python, regex

I have strings that contain placeholders and I want to extract those placeholders.

Example: `" Hello %s,  your balance is %d%%"`

```
q = re.compile(r'\%(\w+)%\]')
p= q.findall(string)
```

^ that doesnt work.

Is there a way to extract both of those placeholders? Even though they have different formats?

Comment: Are these placeholders `%s` and `%d`?

Comment: What do you want to extract? Why you used `\]` in your regex?

Comment: What about all of the optional placeholder components?

Answer (score 3):

```
q = re.compile(r'%(\w+)%?')
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rC2mH4/11

Infact when you dont want `%` you cna use lookaround to make `0 width assertion`.

```
(?<=%)(\w+)%?
```

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rC2mH4/12

Comment: that works well to extract both 's' and 'd' from the string, what if i wanted to extract "%s" and "%d%%"?

Comment: @user1322582 check demo.It extract both.Do you want `%` as well

Comment: yep i need everything up until a white space, this works well: (%\w+\S+)?

Comment: \w  matches word characters[a-zA-Z0-9_], what if i only want to capture numbers and characters, sometimes there are commas, semicolons following the placeholder, example: "%s, " i only need to capture "%s"

Comment: @user1322582 use `[0-9a-zA-Z]` and add wahtever characters you want

Comment: @user1322582 what about when those characters are part of the conversion specification? There is an optional space flag, for example, meaning *"A blank should be left before a positive number (or empty string) produced by a signed conversion."*

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [template strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings).

Then you could simply write:

```
from string import Template
s = Template('Hello $name, your balance is $balance')
print s.substitute(name='user1322582', balance=33)
# output: Hello user1322582, your balance is 33
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) explains the options for the string formatting "conversion specifications"; if you need everything, you could use something like:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = " Hello %s,  your balance is %d%%"
>>> pattern = r'''
    %                            # start of specifier
    (?P<key>\([^\)]*\))?         # optional mapping key
    (?P<flags>[#0\- +])*         # optional conversion flags
    (?P<width>\*|\d*)?           # optional minimum field width
    (?P<precision>\.\*|\.\d*)?   # optional precision
    (?P<lenmod>[hlL])?           # optional length modifier
    (?P<type>[diouxXeEfFgGcrs%]) # conversion type
'''
>>> [g.groupdict() for g in re.finditer(pattern, s, re.VERBOSE)]
[{'precision': None, 'width': None, 'flags': None, 'key': None, 'lengthmod': None, 'type': 's'}, 
 {'precision': None, 'width': None, 'flags': None, 'key': None, 'lengthmod': None, 'type': 'd'}, 
 {'precision': None, 'width': None, 'flags': None, 'key': None, 'lengthmod': None, 'type': '%'}]
```

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/uU0yO2/9). Note that this is wild overkill for your current example, but necessary if you want to handle arbitrary strings.